# Continue WPF gridview alteration

Tags: wpf, gridview

Is it possible to continue the alteration styles in a gridview even when there are no items?

[image]

As you can see, after the last item, the pattern stops.

Comment: Dark gray, light gray, dark gray, light gray

Comment: I really like that style! Any way you could post that to pastebin.com and send me the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, WPF provides a rather elegant way to implement this because its templating mechanism allows you to fill the unused area in a `GridView` with whatever you like.

All you need to do is modify the `ListView` template to paint the unused section of the with a `VisualBrush` that typically consists of two `GridViewItems` stacked vertically (in the general case it will be `AlternationCount` `GridViewItems`).

The only complexity is choosing which color to start with when painting the unused section of the `ScrollViewer`.  This is calculated as `Items.Count` modulo `AlternationCount`.  The solution is to create a simple `Control` that does this calculation and use it in our `ListView` template.  For the sake of my explanation I will call the control "ContinueAlternation".

The `ListView` template which would be mostly the default template with a `local:ContinueAlternation` control added below the `ScrollViewer` using a `DockPanel`, like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
  <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <DockPanel>
      <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
      </ScrollViewer>

      <local:ContinueAlternation
        ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}"
        AlternationCount="{TemplateBinding AlternationCount}"
        ItemsCount="{Binding Items.Count,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />

    </DockPanel>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `ContinueAlternation` control will be displayed as a `Rectangle` painted with a tiled `VisualBrush` containing an `ItemsControl` that shows dummy rows, as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ContinueAlternation}">
  <Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>

      <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None"
                   ViewPortUnits="Absolute"
                   ViewPort="{TemplateBinding ViewportSize}">

        <ItemsControl x:Name="PART_ItemsControl"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
      </VisualBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `DataContext` here will be an array of dummy `ListViewItem` generated in code-behind from the given `AlternationCount` and `ItemsCount`:

```
public class ContinueAlternation
{
  public Style ItemsContainerStyle ... // Declare as DependencyProperty using propdp snippet
  public int AlternationCount ... // Declare as DependencyProperty using propdp snippet
  public int ItemsCount ... // Declare as DependencyProperty using propdp snippet

  protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Property==ItemsContainerStyleProperty ||
       e.Property==AlternationCountProperty ||
       e.Property==ItemsCountProperty)
    {
      // Here is where we build the items for display
      DataContext =
        from index in Enumerable.Range(ItemsCount,
                                       ItemsCount + AlternationCount)
        select BuildItem( index % AlternationCount);
    }
  }
  ListViewItem BuildItem(int alternationIndex)
  {
    var item = new ListViewItem { Style = ItemsContainerStyle };
    ItemsControl.SetAlternationIndex(item, alternationIndex);
    return item;
  }

  protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size desiredSize)
  {
    var ic = (ItemsControl)GetTemplateChild("PART_ItemsControl");
    ic.Width = desiredSize.Width;
    Size result = base.MeasureOverride(desiredSize);
    ViewportSize = new Size(ic.DesiredSize);
    return result;
  }
  public Size ViewportSize ... // Declare as DependencyProperty using propdp snippet
}
```

Note that this same code could be written with `PropertyChangedCallback` instead of `OnPropertyChanged`.

You also need to do something to make sure the blank rows are the desired height.  The easiest way to do this is to set either `MinHeight` or `Content` in your `ItemsContainerStyle`.  Alternatively `ContinueAlternation` could set the height when it constructs each `ListViewItem`.

I typed all this code off the top of my head, but it is similar to code I've written and used before so it ought to work basically as-is.